# Unable to run VSTS Agents on Kubernetes using Azure Devops

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

I recently spun [this](https://github.com/Azure/helm-vsts-agent) chart up on kubernetes. It has been archived. These are the changes I have made to get it to run:

#### Image

Changed the image from `microsoft/vsts-agent` to `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-pipelines/vsts-agent`
Changed the tags from `latest` to `ubuntu-16.04-docker-17.12.0-ce`

#### Limits

Reduced the limits from 4 CPU and 8Gbi to 1 and 1 respectively because I'm cheap and am using weak VMs.

#### Api Version

Changed from `apiVersion: apps/v1beta2` to `apiVersion: apps/v1` to allow for Statefulset

---

That being said everything spun up and was healthy on the cluster. So far so good, right? Well. Not so good.

The next step was to actually use the agents. I setup Azure Devops with the agent pool and configured a very simple pipeline using the GUI.

[image]

Step 1 succeeds but step 2 fails. So this is where I'm down the rabbit hole. The chart uses a mounted docker-socket which I believe has been removed from AKS ([read about this here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops#use-azure-kubernetes-service-cluster)).

I am not sure why step 1 would succeed, telling me that docker is installed, but step 2 fails citing that it cannot find docker.

The main error I am seeing: `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

---

Is there an alternative solution out there? Right now I just paid for a hosted agent on Devops just to get some builds through but I do not want to do this, I want to use Kubernetes if possible to run these agents.

Answer (score 2):

Running on (any recent version) of AKS you cannot use docker-in-docker (which is what you want to do here). See this article for the limitations that got introduced when AKS switched to containerd: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/cluster-configuration#containerd-limitationsdifferences

As an alternative I suggest using [VMSS-self hosted Build Agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops). Works like a charm for me. Use cloud-init to define the software you want to have and ADO takes care of scaling up and down your agents.

Comment: I appreciate the response but I am really hoping for a kubernetes based approach.

Comment: see here for examples. Using ACR tasks might be a viable option https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/container-image-builds-on-kubernetes-clusters-with-containerd/ba-p/2121535

Comment: I will look into this @silent. If it proves to be within the spirit of the question I'll favourite your response. Really appreciate this.